# Pass column name from _V_SYS_COLUMNS table to create a dynamic select query in Netezza

Tags: dynamic, dynamic-sql, netezza, aginity, nzsql

I need to create a single dynamic **select query** for different tables in Netezza.

I get the list of columns for any table by using following query:

**select *
from _V_SYS_COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Table Name'**

But I need to append all the values of Column ‘Column_Name’ separated by comma and store it into a variable:

var= col1,col2,....

And then I will pass this ‘var’ in select query to run it for different tables.

**Note:** I cannot use Select * because all the columns are not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ COLUMNS=`nzsql -A -t -c "select column_name from _v_sys_columns where table_name = 'NZ_CHECK_DISK_SCAN_SPEEDS';"  -R "," | sed -e "s/,$//"`

$ echo "$COLUMNS"
THE_DATASLICE,THE_EXTENT,THE_PAGE,THE_ROW,FILLER1,FILLER2
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your response! I am new to Netezza and my Netezza is installed on Windows machine. I am running the queries on Aginity Workbench. I think your suggestions can be implemented on Unix or Netezza commandline. Could you please suggest something which I can implement on Windows.

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: I just added a bit of context on Mark’s behalf :)